# Error can not convert Object to table

Tags: c#, rest, api

```
//POST api/values
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/post")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]classUser usuario)
{
    try
    {
        bool resultado = false;

        if (usuario == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("user can`t be null");

        classUser usr = new classUser();
        usr.ID = usuario.ID;
        usr.name = usuario.name;
        usr.email = usuario.email;
        usr.bio = usuario.bio;

        dc.tb_User.InsertOnSubmit(usr);
        dc.SubmitChanges();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, resultado);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I am developing an api rest, but I get the error message in that line

```
dc.tb_User.InsertOnSubmit (usr);
```

Can not convert object to my table in SQL database, showing this compile error:

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'api4food.Models.classUser' to 'api4food.tb_User'   api4food

Comment: What is the **exact** exception message  you get? Any inner exceptions?

Comment: Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'api4food.Models.classUser' to 'api4food.tb_User' api4food

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `InsertOnSubmit` expects an instance of type `tb_User`, not of 
 type `classUser`.

So your mapping should be like this:

```
// other code omitted
// assuming tb_User has the same shape as classUser
var usr = new tb_User 
{
    ID = usuario.ID,
    name = usuario.name,
    email = usuario.email,
    bio = usuario.bio
};

dc.tb_User.InsertOnSubmit(usr);
```

Or adapt the propertynames that exist on tb_User accordingly.